# How can I keep my projectiles direction constant after it is fired

Tags: godot, gdscript, projectile

I am making a simple platformer in Godot to learn to code and learn the engine.
I have a "Bullet" scene which looks like this:

```
extends Area2D

const SPEED = 100
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var Player = Global.player

func _physics_process(delta):
    if Player.playerDirection == 1:
        velocity.x = SPEED * delta
        translate(velocity)
        $Sprite.flip_h = true
    if Player.playerDirection == -1:
        velocity.x = -SPEED * delta
        translate(velocity)

func _on_VisibilityNotifier2D_screen_exited():
    queue_free()
```

I'm using my players direction to dictate which direction my projectile should be moving, but the problem is that as soon as I start running in the other direction with my player, the projectile changes direction and moves the same way as the player.

Any ideas as how to fix this issue would be appreciated! I'm not so great at coding yet so I'm really stumped.

Answer (score 2):

Don't hold references to the player in the bullet. It just needs the set velocity. Set it when you create the bullet.

The bullet code can be as simple as (note no references to `Player`):

```
extends Area2D

const SPEED = 100
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta):
    translate(velocity * SPEED * delta)

func _on_VisibilityNotifier2D_screen_exited():
    queue_free()
```

How does it gets its `velocity` value? Another scripts sets it when it creates a new bullet. For example:

```
const Bullet = preload("res://scenes/Bullet/Bullet.tscn")

var Player = Global.player

func shoot():
    var bullet = Bullet.instance()
    bullet.velocity.x = Player.playerDirection
    add_child(bullet)
```

In this code I'm using `preload`, which will give you a [`PackedScene`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_packedscene.html), from which you can create instances using the `instance` method.

*This is just an example. I don't know how the code that creates a new bullet looks like, nor where it is. Adapt it as needed.*

Answer (score 1):

Your bullet needs to have its own velocity and position. Set the initial values of the velocity and position only on creation of the bullet (they can be relative to the player.) You now should have two entities in the scene: the player and the bullet. They can then both be updated separately given their speed values.

Comment: But how would I get the bullet to go in the right direction? I'm not sure how to do this without using the players direction

Comment: @CapnCoin You initialize the bullet's velocity (direction and speed) relative to the player's but after than it updates on its own irrelevant to the player's own values.